# Convert nested json to Cassandra

Tags: json, cassandra, nosql

I run into a problem when trying to convert json data to Cassandra.

The json data is like:

```
{
  "A": {
    "A_ID" : "1111"
    "field1": "value1",
"field2": "value2",
"field3": [
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "name1",
    "segment": [
      {
        "segment_id": "segment_id_1",
        "segment_name": "segment_name_1",
        "segment_value": "segment_value_1"
      },
      {
        "segment_id": "segment_id_2",
        "segment_name": "segment_name_2",
        "segment_value": "segment_value_2"
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "name": "name2",
    "segment": [
      {
        "segment_id": "segment_id_3",
        "segment_name": "segment_name_3",
        "segment_value": "segment_value_3"
      },
      {
        "segment_id": "segment_id_4",
        "segment_name": "segment_name_4",
        "segment_value": "segment_value_4"
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
  }
}
```

Thank you very much!

I see a post about composite keys here:
https://pkghosh.wordpress.com/2013/07/14/storing-nested-objects-in-cassandra-composite_columns/

But I do not know what does this post mean because the author did not give a complete solution.

Comment: It's not clear what your question actually is?

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, you should keep entire json string in database.

For example – You can create a table for "segement" part of the json.

```
Create table segment_by_id{
 Id text,
 Name text,
 Json text,
 PRIMARY KEY (id, name)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (name DESC);
```

This way you can divide  the json part by part. You can also save the entire json in one table with primary and clustering keys  suitable to your needs.
Cassandra uses LZ4 compression so large data can be saved efficiently. Go through [Compression](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_config_compress_t.html) documentation to use a compression algoritham for table.